# string to integer conversion in batch

Tags: batch-file

1. Script stores the lines along with line numbers where ever "firstword" is found, those line numbers are retrieved from temp_onsetTime.txt. trying to retrieve the 4th line from that line number and write it in another file.
2. line set var=%%g% set /a var=%var% + 4 , string var is not getting converted into integer.

```dos
cls
break>ontset_time.txt 
break>temp_ontsetTime.txt
set firstword="stimuli\1200.wav"
set secondword="MainScreen.OnsetTime" 
findstr /l /I /n %firstword% "C:\Users\BHAVYA\Desktop\AudOdd.txt">>temp_ontsetTime.txt
for /F " delims=: tokens=1 " %%g in ( C:\Users\BHAVYA\Desktop\temp_ontsetTime.txt ) do (
 echo %%g
 echo.
 set var=%%g%
 set /a var=%var% + 4
 echo %var%
 for /F " delims=: tokens=1,2 skip= %var%"  %%h IN ( ' findstr /l /I %secondword% "C:\Users\BHAVYA\Desktop\AudOdd.txt" ' ) do (
  echo %%h %%i
  echo %%i%>>ontset_time.txt
  goto loop_end
  )
 :loop_end 
 echo loop ended
)        

pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1: `set var=%%g%` is incorrect; `set var=%%g` is closer (`%%g` accesses the metavariable `%%g`); `set /a var=%%g` is better still (since `%%g` is apparently an integer).

Problem2: You need to learn about `delayed expansion` - there are hundreds of references here on SO. Batch replaces every `%var%` with its value as it stands when the `for` loop is **parsed** - not when it is executed, hence

```
set /a = var + 4
```

will increase the value of `var` by 4 - you then need to use

```
call echo %%var%%
```

to access the *changed* value of `var` if you are not using **delayed expansion**.

AAMOI, this is equivalent to

```
set /a var=%%g+4
```

Third problem - still the `delayedexpansion` problem - `%var%` will be replaced by its value at the time `for...%%g...` was parsed, not the value as modified within the loop.

Fourth problem : labels are not allowed within a `block statement` (a parenthesised series of statements).

Here's a cure without `delayed expansion`

```
for /F " delims=: tokens=1 " %%g in ( C:\Users\BHAVYA\Desktop\temp_ontsetTime.txt ) do (
 echo %%g
 echo.
 set /a var=%%g + 4
 call echo %%var%%
 for /f "tokens=1,2delims==" %%m in ('set var') do if /i "%%m"=="var" (
  echo var is %%n
  set "show=Y"
  for /F " delims=: tokens=1,2 skip=%%n"  %%h IN ( ' findstr /l /I %secondword% "C:\Users\BHAVYA\Desktop\AudOdd.txt" ' ) do if defined show (
   echo %%h %%i
   set "show="
   echo %%i%>>ontset_time.txt
  )
 )
 echo loop ended
)
```

Note here that using `set var` will list the **current** environment values that begin `var` in the format `var=99`. We tokenise that on `=` and the first token (`%%m`) must be `var`, not `var1` or anything else. If it is, its value is in `%%n`, so `set` the flag `show` to a value (any value will do) and then process the file. On the first "hit", clear the value in `show`- it is now undefined, so no more processing takes place until the next outer loop starts.

[I obviously can't test this]